# DTLS support over Arduino Ethernet UDP or WIfi UDP

Tags: arduino, ethernet, coap, dtls

I have implemented COAP protocol over EthernetUDP and WIFIUDP as well. I now need to add Datagram level transport layer security (DTLS). Does EthernetUdp or WifiUdp support DTLS ??

Thanks,
Jyoti Raj Sharma